# In groovy what are the best way to check if in array at least one element is not null?

Tags: groovy

I have a code as below. It working but I wonder what is the best way to write it (more readable, shorter)

```
private static boolean isAnyNotNull(String ... args) {
    for (String item: args) {
        if (item != null) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: `args.any { it != null }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can replace your function with

```
private static boolean isAnyNotNull(String ... args) {
    args.any { it != null }
}
```